# jQuery morphing button concept - fadeIn() not always working

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/h405kbaa/

Sometimes the `button.fadeIn(300);` (Line 78 and 171) don't seem to work.

Usually, if you press the first button, close it, press the second button, close it, open the first button again, then close it, the button will not fadeIn but instead be hidden with `display:none;`. Why is this happening?

jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    // fix span and display on button

    var morphObject = {

        button: $('button.morphButton'),
        container: $('div.morphContainer'),
        overlay: $('div.overlay'),
        content: $('h1.content, p.content'),

        endPosition: {
            top: 100,
            left: '50%',
            width: 600,
            height: 400,
            marginLeft: -300
        },


        init: function() {
            var mO = morphObject,
                button = mO.button;

            button.on('click', function() {
                button.fadeOut(200);
                setTimeout(mO.containerMove, 200);
            });

        },

        containerMove: function() {
            var mO = morphObject,
                content = mO.content,
                overlay = mO.overlay,
                container = mO.container,
                span = $('span.close');

            overlay.fadeIn();
            container.addClass('active');

            container.animate(mO.endPosition, 400, function() {
                    content.fadeIn();
                    span.fadeIn();
                    mO.close();
            });

        },

        close: function() {
            var mO = morphObject,
                container = mO.container,
                overlay = mO.overlay,
                content = mO.content;

            if ( container.find('span.close').length ) return;

            $('<span class="close">X</span>').appendTo(container);

            var span = $('span.close');

            span.on('click', function() {
                content.fadeOut();
                span.fadeOut();
                overlay.fadeOut();
                setTimeout(mO.animateBack, 200);
            });

        },

        animateBack: function() {
            var mO = morphObject,
                container = mO.container;
                button = mO.button;

            container.animate(mO.startPosition, 400, function() {
                    container.removeClass('active');
                    button.fadeIn(300);
            });

        }

    }

    // End of morphObject One

    var container = morphObject.container;

    morphObject.startPosition = {
        top: container.css('top'),
        left: container.css('left'),
        width: container.css('width'),
        height: container.css('height'),
        marginLeft: container.css('margin-left')
    };


    var morphObjectTwo = {

        button: $('button.newButton'),
        container: $('div.newContainer'),
        overlay: $('div.overlay'),
        content: $('h1.newContent, p.newContent'),

        endPosition: {
            top: 100,
            left: '50%',
            width: 600,
            height: 400,
            marginLeft: -300
        },


        init: function() {
            var mO = morphObjectTwo,
                button = mO.button;

            button.on('click', function() {
                button.fadeOut(200);
                setTimeout(mO.containerMove, 200);
            });

        },

        containerMove: function() {
            var mO = morphObjectTwo,
                content = mO.content,
                overlay = mO.overlay,
                container = mO.container,
                span = $('span.close');

            overlay.fadeIn();
            container.addClass('active');

            container.animate(mO.endPosition, 400, function() {
                    content.fadeIn();
                    span.fadeIn();
                    mO.close();
            });

        },

        close: function() {
            var mO = morphObjectTwo,
                container = mO.container,
                overlay = mO.overlay,
                content = mO.content;

            if ( container.find('span.close').length ) return;

            $('<span class="close">X</span>').appendTo(container);

            var span = $('span.close');

            span.on('click', function() {
                content.fadeOut();
                span.fadeOut();
                overlay.fadeOut();
                setTimeout(mO.animateBack, 200);
            });

        },

        animateBack: function() {
            var mO = morphObjectTwo,
                container = mO.container;
                button = mO.button;

            container.animate(mO.startPosition, 400, function() {
                    container.removeClass('active');
                    button.fadeIn(300);
            });

        }

    }

    var container = morphObjectTwo.container;

    morphObjectTwo.startPosition = {
        top: container.css('top'),
        left: container.css('left'),
        width: container.css('width'),
        height: container.css('height'),
        marginLeft: container.css('margin-left')
    };

    morphObject.init();
    morphObjectTwo.init();

});
```

Please note, the jQuery contains two objects which are identical, only with different properties for different buttons, containers, etc. This means you need to change the code on both objects. The first object ends on line 85, and the second ends on line 176. Both objects are called at the bottom.

Answer (score 0):

Just remove this line from js script

```
button.fadeOut(200);
```

Comment: That would destory the whole concept.. It's a morphing button.

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out...

Didn't correctly define the variables:

```
    animateBack: function() {
        var mO = morphObject,
            container = mO.container;
            button = mO.button;
```

Should be:

```
    animateBack: function() {
        var mO = morphObject,
            container = mO.container,
            button = mO.button;
```

(The comma).